# Export arbitrary symbols in C

Tags: c, linux, linker, clang

Lets say that I have translation unit 1:

```
struct SomeData {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
} some_data;

union Union1 {
    unsigned char buf[1024];
    struct {
        unsigned char _pad0[8];
        int some_int;
    };
} union1;
```

And, in another, translation unit 2:

```
extern int some_int;
extern int some_data_var2;
```

I would like to make it so that the symbol `some_int` in translation unit 2 shares the same memory as `union1.some_int` in translation unit 1.  And likewise, I would like `some_data_var2` in translation unit 2 to share the same memory as `some_data.var2` in translation unit 2.  How can I do this?

This is on Linux

Comment: There is no such language C/C++, make your choice

Comment: For C, in translation unit 1, you could define `int *some_int = &union1.some_int;`, and, in translation unit 2, declare `extern int *some_int;`. Of course, this means you must use `*some_int` for the reference rather than `some_int`. That could be concealed with a macro that replaces `some_int`, which is not a great idea, but the aliasing of a structure or union member with another identifier is not a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @Slava, Yes, you are correct, I have updated the question

Comment: There is no way to directly achieve your desired result in standard C, nor in standard C++.   There might be platform-specific ways to do it, but you’ve not identified your platform and it probably isn’t possible even then.  It would require fancy directions to the linker.  If you can use pointers or functions, you can get close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wedded to exposing them directly as raw `int`s?

Because if you're not, you can just add

```
int& some_int() { return union1.some_int; }
int& some_data_var2() { return some_data.var2; }
```

to the first translation unit, and then declare those functions in a header (or, if you must, directly in translation unit 2).

---

Edit: since you removed the C++ tag *after* I wrote this, just change the references to pointers.

Comment: Apologies for changing the question on you

Comment: That's OK (although the "C or C++ - pick one" comment is always true) - the answer's roughly the same anyway